# spring access beans during context initialisation

Tags: spring

I want to access the Spring Applciation Context , when the entityManagerFactory is getting initialised.
We can use ApplicationContextAware , but the entityManagerFactory gets instantiated before our ApplicationContextAware bean is initialised.
Share if anybody has done something like this .

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass entitymanagerfactory and give it a constructor with ApplicationContext, and wire the context into the constructor.
Note that tampering with the applicationcontext while it's still being initialized is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the bean to use `ApplicationContextAware` and then set the `SessionFactory` bean's `depends-on` attribute to the context aware bean.  This should cause the bean to be created prior to the `sessionFactory`.